# jQuery CSS scale transform not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

jQuery:

```
var scale_width = 1;
var scale_height = 1.5;
$(".english_canvas.unit_11").css("transform","scale('"+scale_width+"','"+scale_height+"')");
```

HTML:

```
<div style="width: 210px; height: 210px; background-color: #fff" class="english_canvas unit_11"></div>
```

Comment: `"scale(" + scale_width+", " + scale_height+")"` is enough. Don't enclose scale values in `''`.

Comment: $(".english_canvas.unit_11").css("transform","scale("+scale_width+","+scale_height+")");

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".english_canvas.unit_11").css("transform","scale("+scale_width+","+scale_height+")");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="width: 210px; height: 210px; background-color: #000" class="english_canvas unit_11"></div>


var scale_width = 1;
var scale_height = 3.5;
$(".english_canvas.unit_11").css({
  "-webkit-transform":"scale("+scale_width+","+scale_height+")"})
```